# Find and Replace in Visual Studio using Regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I found out that you can use Regex for search queries in Find and Replace in Visual Studio. I have a lot of similar lines like so:

`datum["Id"] = id;
datum["Name"] = name;`

I also have more lines like so:

`this.Id = datum["Id"];
this.Name = datum["Name"];`

I want to turn the first lines to:

`datum.Set("Id", id);
datum.Set("Name", name);`

And the second set of lines to:

`this.Id = datum.Get<int>("Id");
this.Name = datum.Get<int>("Name");`

How is it possible to do with Find and Replace and Regex? I can't figure it out.

Comment: BTW, your strings are too easy to be not use with the REGEX. More useful use of regex is to find patterns not complete strings.

Answer (score 0):

After enabling regular expression by clicking on 'use Regular Expression' button, Place following in find:

`datum\[\"Id\"\]\s*=\s*id\;`

and place following in replace (no need to use regex in replace):

```
datum.Set("Id", id);
```

Similarly:

In Find:

```
datum\[\"Name\"\]\s*=\s*name\;
```

In replace:

```
datum.Set("Name", name);
```

In Find:

```
this\.Id\s*=\s*datum\[\"Id\"\]\;
```

In Replace:

```
this.Id = datum.Get<int>("Id");
```

In Find:

```
this\.Name\s*=\s*datum\[\"Name\"\]\;
```

In Replace:

```
this.Name = datum.Get<int>("Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need universal Regex with substitutions in replace field.

This expression:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\["([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)"\] = ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+);
```

matches your first lines.

You should input that in "Find..." field.

This expression allows you to make replacements you need:

```
$1.Set("$2", $3);
```

Put it to the "Replace..." field.

Numbered expressions like this `$n` in replacement targets to groups in original Regex that defined by `(...)` and numbered in sequential order.

So, replacement for your second lines would be like that:

Find: `(this.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+) = ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\["([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)"\];`

Replacement: `$1 = $2.Get<int>("$3");`

You could find more information on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx)

P.S. Feel free to ask more question for details.

Comment: `([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\["([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)"\] = ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+);` will not only replace `datum...` but `hello...` too. This is too broad, and will ruin the code.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams Does my answer was helpful for you? Mark it as answer, please, if it does.